# How to capture submit event using jQuery in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms, form-submit

I'm trying to handle the `submit` event of a `form` element using jQuery.

```
    $("form").bind("submit", function() {
        alert("You are submitting!");
    });
```

This never fires when the form submits (as part of a postback, e.g. when I click on a button or linkbutton).

Is there a way to make this work? I could attach to events of the individual elements that trigger the submission, but that's less than ideal - there are just too many possibilities (e.g. dropdownlists with autopostback=true, keyboard shortcuts, etc.)

---

**Update:** Here's a minimal test case - this is the entire contents of my aspx page:

```
<%@ page language="vb" autoeventwireup="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" enablepartialrendering="true">
                <scripts>
                    <asp:scriptreference path="/Standard/Core/Javascript/Jquery.min.js" />
                </scripts>
            </asp:scriptmanager>
            <p>
                <asp:linkbutton id="TestButton" text="Click me!" runat="server" /></p>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert("Document ready.");
            $("form").submit(function() {
                alert("Submit detected.");
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the "Document ready" alert, but not the "Submit detected" when clicking on the linkbutton.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Thanks, @Ken Browning and @russau for pointing me in the direction of hijacking `__doPostBack`.
I've seen a couple of different approaches to this:

1. Hard-code my own version of `__doPostBack`, and put it later on the page so that it overwrites the standard one.
2. Overload `Render` on the page and inject my own custom code into the existing `__doPostBack`.
3. Take advantage of Javascript's functional nature and create a hook for adding functionality to `__doPostBack`.

The first two seem undesirable for a couple of reasons (for example, suppose in the future someone else needs to add their own functionality to `__doPostBack`) so I've gone with #3.

This `addToPostBack` function is a variation of a common pre-jQuery technique I used to use to add functions to `window.onload,` and it works well:

```
addToPostBack = function(func) {
    var old__doPostBack = __doPostBack;
    if (typeof __doPostBack != 'function') {
        __doPostBack = func;
    } else {
        __doPostBack = function(t, a) {
            if (func(t, a)) old__doPostBack(t, a);
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("Document ready.");
    addToPostBack(function(t,a) {
        return confirm("Really?")
    });
});
```

**Edit:** Changed `addToPostBack` so that

1. It can take the same arguments as `__doPostBack`.
2. The function being added takes place before `__doPostBack`.
3. The function being added can return `false` to abort postback.

Comment: great solution to show a loading notification with jQuery while using AutoPostBack for controls in update panels.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer!  I was having a really hard time with this in Sharepoint, but couldn't figure out why.  I thought I would leave a comment in case anyone else was sttruggling with this.  For Sharepoint, in addition to your code, you need to add the following right before your anonymous function returns: _spFormOnSubmitCalled = false;

Comment: Great thanks for sharing this. I was just having the opposite problem - a jQuery handler for the form's submit event was being fired (and showing a loading gif) but _doPostBack wasn't being called because validation failed. Very strange, but no longer a problem!

Comment: I took this solution and put it in a jQuery plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/beforePostBack/

Answer (score 15):

I've had success with [a solution with overriding `__doPostBack()`](http://kenbrowning.blogspot.com/2009/01/supporting-jquerys-formsubmit-in-aspnet.html) so as to call an override on `form.submit()` (i.e. `$('form:first').submit(myHandler)`), but I think it's over-engineered. As of ASP.NET 2.0, the most simple workaround is to:

1. Define a javascript function that you want to run when the form is submitted i.e.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   function myhandler()
   {
       alert('you submitted!');
   }

   </script>
   ```
2. Register your handler function within your codebehind i.e.

   ```
   protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnLoad(e);
       ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Page, Page.GetType(), 
                                               "myHandlerKey", "myhandler()");
   }
   ```

That's all! `myhandler()` will be called from straightforward button-input submits and automatic `__doPostBack()` calls alike.

Comment: Just to clarify, in your example "myHandlerKey" is the id of the  form tag.  Like this:  <form id="myHandlerKey" runat="server">

Comment: Sorry, no - check the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301794.aspx. The *key* uniquely identifies the script to help prevent duplicate registration. Incidentally there should be no need to uniquely identify a form element as webforms only allow one form per page.

Comment: To clarify: webforms only allow one form per page declared with *runat="server"*. You may have other non-server forms on the page.

Comment: I like this. It's the proper ".NET way" of handling things.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, this is annoying.  I replace `__doPostBack` with my own so that I could get submit events to fire.

Iirc, this is an issue when submitting a form via javascript (which calls to `__doPostBack` do) in IE (maybe other browsers too).

My `__doPostBack` replacement calls `$(theForm).submit()` after replicating the default behavior (stuffing values in hidden inputs)

Comment: Hijacking __doPostBack : http://weblogs.asp.net/vga/archive/2004/03/01/NoMoreHijackingOfDoPostBackInWhidbey.aspx

Comment: @russau - It's my impression from the article that postback hijacking shouldn't be necessary as of Whidbey (VS2005)?

Comment: @Herb Well, their cause for hijacking is different than yours.  It sounds like their cause has been addressed.  Yours definitely has not.  If you want jQuery submit events to be fired whenever a postback is initiated by a call to __doPostBack then you'll need to hijack __doPostBack.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it with jQuery, but you could add an OnClientClick property to the ASP.NET control:

```
<asp:linkbutton id="TestButton" text="Click me!" runat="server" OnClientClick="alert('Submit detected.');" />
```

Comment: This doesn't help in my situation. First, if I was going to handle every single control that might trigger a postback, it would be a better solution to use jQuery to capture events on these across the board. But what I need is a global solution on lots of different forms, and I don't want to go back and touch every single control that could possible trigger a postback.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET Framework 3.5 or up, you can use **ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement()** in your server-side code. The registered script will get called both on normal submit and on DoPostback.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this, this.GetType(), "myKey", "SomeClientSideFunction();");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for capturing the submit:

```
$("form input[type=submit]").live("click", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form submittion triggered");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

          $(this).live("submit", function () {

                console.log("submitted");
             }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add OnclientClick to linkbutton

OnClientClick="if(!$('#form1').valid()) return false;"