# JavaScript: Determine which control caused postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick, postback, submit

I am currently developing a web site using ASP.NET 3.5. On a page there are some situations I don't want that a specific control will cause a postback to the server. I wrote a function to return false if that condition is met which will be called when the onsubmit-Event occurs. But I somehow need to determine which control will cause the postback, because the postback should be cancelled only if this specific control caused it under certain conditions. How it is possible to do that?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

> How does `ASP.NET` recognize the control
>   responsible for handling the postback?
>   When no controls referenced in the
>   request body implement the
>   `IPostBackEventHandler` interface, the
>   page class looks for the `__EVENTTARGET`
>   hidden field, if any. The contents of
>   the field is assumed to be the `ID` of
>   the control that caused the postback.
>   If this control implements the
>   `IPostBackEventHandler` interface, the
>   `RaisePostbackEvent` method is invoked.

this is from here - [The Client Side of ASP.NET Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163512.aspx).

So at the client-side `__EVENTTARGET` is all you need. At the server-side you could either override the [`Page.RaisePostBackEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.raisepostbackevent.aspx) method (this is protected method, so you could inherit from [`System.Web.UI.Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class):

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, 
                                           string eventArgument)
{
    // sourceControl is a control that caused postback
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(sourceControl, eventArgument);
}
```

or perform the same without inherining:

```
var controlName = page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
Control postbackControl = null;
if (!string.IsnullOrEmpty(controlName))
{
    postbackControl = this.Page.FindControl(controlName);
}
```

**EDIT:** regarding the author's comment to my answer: if `__EVENTTARGET` value is an empty string, it seems you're getting this value before it is been set in `__doPostBack` function. So the workaround could be in *overriding* `__doPostBack` function or a similar way; you could find an example of doing it in this [SO quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230573/how-to-capture-submit-event-using-jquery-in-an-asp-net-application/1234845#1234845).

Comment: Hello, to query the control that caused the postback at the server-side would be too late, because I want to prevent postback. So I tried to get the value of the hidden field ___EVENTTARGET_ handling the event _onsubmit_ but its value is always an empty string.

Comment: Thank you. The Link you provided helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the `ScriptManager.GetCurrent().AsyncPostBackSourceElementID` to find the control that caused the postback to the page.

More details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.asyncpostbacksourceelementid.aspx) but it will work in these instances:

- A postback from a control that is
  inside an UpdatePanel control whose
  ChildrenAsTriggers property is set to
  true (the default).
- A postback from a control that is a trigger for an UpdatePanel control.
- A postback from a control that is registered by calling the
  RegisterAsyncPostBackControl method
  of the ScriptManager control.

I don't know if you're using UpdatePanels but it seems likely as this is the only situation I can think of where you'd need to know which control is causing the postback.

Comment: Hello, I don't use an update panel. My situation is that there is a DropDownList on my page. Every time another item is selected a postback is caused. I want to prevent that postback if the first value in the list is selected because it's an invalid entry (just for information) and if a value is selected but the related information is already shown.