# Need to call a Javascript function from .aspx (VB.net) page any time a postback happens

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a large .aspx page, with multiple server controls. And, there is also a JavaScript file referenced by this .aspx page. I want to have a JavaScript function within this existing .js file, that will get called before any postback that happens to the server.

[note: I have seen another post that mention how to do this in JQuery ( [How to capture submit event using jQuery in an ASP.NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230573/how-to-capture-submit-event-using-jquery-in-an-asp-net-application) ), but I would  like that to be done through the existing JavaScript file, rather than using a new technology like JQuery]

[Edited] <s>Solution of using OnSubmit handler will not work for me...because it will not get called for postbacks that get triggered by server controls.</s>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
/* 
   usually there is only one form in asp.net, but if you know you can have 
   more than one, you can get main form with document.getElementById
*/
var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];     
if (form.addEventListener) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', functionThatShouldBeCalledBeforeSubmit, false); 
} else if (form.attachEvent)  {
    form.attachEvent('onsubmit', functionThatShouldBeCalledBeforeSubmit);
}
```

`onsubmit` event will rise any time form is submitted. No matter how.

More details about attaching events with JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: "//asp.net allows only one form on a page" - not quite right. you can have as many forms as you like. You can only have one server-side form visible at any time. So you would be better getting the form by its ID. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: @Darren Hm... yes. If it is outside runat="server" form, it will be sent to client (just checked that) ). Agree. I tried to place it inside .ascx control and it was silently removed by asp.net and that misleaded me.

Comment: This will not work for the postbacks that get triggered by server controls, right?