# add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler) causing my javascript to popup twice

Tags: javascript, .net

I have this function in my .aspx file in the beginning

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function onPageLoad() {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    }

</script>
```

Now in my javascript I have a function called validate that validates some conditional fields on the form.

```
 function validate() {
// calls  alert

alert("Field is blank");

}
```

Now I also have this function called `EndRequesthandler` which simply calls my validate.

```
 function EndRequestHandler() {
  validate();
```

}

Now for some reason, if I leave a field blank then popup pops tiwce when I click a SUBMIT button which is under a update panel and does asynchrous postback. I cannot have this field under Required because its required based on another drop downlist. so its conditional. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean pageLoad (from MS Ajax Library) or onPageLoad? If later, how it is executed?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an odd implementation of essentially trying to run a client side validation script before the form is submitted if I'm not mistaken?

I suggest you try implementing James McCormack's answer found here: [How to capture submit event using jQuery in an ASP.NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230573/how-to-capture-submit-event-using-jquery-in-an-asp-net-application)

Comment: onPageLoad is called in the body tag of the page onload="onPageLoad();"

Comment: Oli Gray, I should have been eloborate, client side validation takes place when user clicks the submit button which does a post back, but before that fields are validated on the form and submitted to database. I added the end_Request because i was having trouble to generate a note by javascript which is done by just changing a dropdown value an submitting again to check whether a note was already generated or not.

Comment: I found out that by adding the following  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().remove_endRequest(EndRequestHandler) to the function onPageLoad stopped the popup coming up again. But it also stopped  my validate() function being called after 3rd atempt on the same page without reloading. so how to reset .add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler) without refreshing the page.